# не запускаются тесты C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
может я что то не подключил, помогите пожалуйста
nUnity ставил через "manager NuGet"

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using static NUnit.Framework.Assert;

namespace TestTDD
{
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    [Test]
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        var viewModel = new Class1();
        AreEqual(4, viewModel.MethodCalc(2, 2));
    }

    [Test]
    public static void TestOneMemory()
    {
        string a = "";
        string b = "";
        AreSame(a, b);
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Минус вопросу за оформление. Код надо прикладывать не картинкой, а текстом. Отдельно я бы ещё пять минусов поставил человеку, который не скопировал текст исключения, а закрыл себе самому возможность получить ответ на свой вопрос. У вас на картинке написано "Тест не запущен: Загрузка сборки TestDDD проопущена потому что" и дальше обрезано. Удачи и помните, что хорошо заданный вопрос - половина ответа.

Comment: В окне отображается сообщение об ошибке (https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0mgE.png). Попробуйте скопировать полный текст и вставить его в вопрос.

Comment: Вот так намного лучше, минус я свой снял. Но в сообщении об ошибке пишется о том, что у вас не поддерживается такая версия nunit. Дописывайте в вопрос информацию, что у вас за проект, как ставили nunit. В самом коде ошибок нет, должно работать.

Comment: Желтеньким отмечена причина, читаем внимательно... Не та версия NUnit у вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил версию nUnit на более ранюю(2.6.1) и заработало, но все равно вопрос остался, а почему с более новой версией такой фейл?

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы вы дописали в вопрос информацию о параметрах вашего проекта. Так что вопрос ваш вряд ли останется отвеченным, разве что наугад тыкать причины - вдруг да угадаешь.

Comment: использовал последнюю версию nunit 3.10, visual studio 2015, поменял вижлу на 2017 и все заработало